# xslt 1.0 help performing task on first element and different on proceeding elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I need to assign a variable once when the first node of many similar nodes appear. My end goal is trying to call the same template over and over from within the main template while storing variables and incrementing them.

Example XML:

```
<!-- Removed See below examples -->
```

Example XSL:

```
<!-- Removed See below examples -->
```

I will do my best to explain what's going on:
`$value` is referenced from the main template that matches on `/ROOT`. The output XML needs to have an index on `FILE_ITEM_NBR` that is incremental everytime it is created. FILE_ITEM_NBR will be generated once outside of the loop and can be staticically set to 1. The other times it's generated are based upon the number of invoices and in this example it's twice per invoice for 3 invoices.

Im using the text from `/ROOT/INVOICES/INVOICES_ROW/INV_ID` as my starting number, because the number after the hypenated(-) portion of the value is generated based on row number.

I need to grab this number the first time through the loop and populate `$value`. Any other time I need to reference that number add a static number to it such as its occurrence in the XSL transformation. In the example I show `$value + 2` and `$value + 3`. Then I need to store that value so that each time the loop iterates I keep adding to it.

I hope this explanation was good enough.

In short I need FILE_ITEM_NBR to be uniquely generated every time it appears during the XSL transformation.

EDIT: **_______________________________________________________________________________________**

I have modified the above XML and XSL examples. The following examples run and the output provided is generated.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
<STUFF/>
<FILE_ITEM_NBR>

</FILE_ITEM_NBR>
<CLIENTNAME>TEST CLIENT</CLIENTNAME>
<INVOICES>
    <INVOICES_ROW>
        <INV_ID>67447-1</INV_ID>
        <INV_TEST1/>
        <INV_TEST2/>
        <INV_TEST3/>
        <MAT_NAME>BLAH BLAH BLAH 1</MAT_NAME>
        <TK_ID>1</TK_ID>
        <EXP_ID>3</EXP_ID>
    </INVOICES_ROW>
    <INVOICES_ROW>
        <INV_ID>12341-2</INV_ID>
        <INV_TEST1/>
        <INV_TEST2/>
        <INV_TEST3/>
        <MAT_NAME>BLAH BLAH BLAH 2</MAT_NAME>
        <TK_ID>2</TK_ID>
        <EXP_ID>3</EXP_ID>
    </INVOICES_ROW>
    <INVOICES_ROW>
        <INV_ID>142445-3</INV_ID>
        <INV_TEST1/>
        <INV_TEST2/>
        <INV_TEST3/>
        <MAT_NAME>BLAH BLAH BLAH 3</MAT_NAME>
        <TK_ID>3</TK_ID>
        <EXP_ID>3</EXP_ID>
    </INVOICES_ROW>
</INVOICES>
</ROOT>
```

EXAMPLE XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template name="INV_ID">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="boolean(.)">
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="normalize-space(./INV_ID)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="'-'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:param name="substr"/>
    <!-- Extract the string which comes after the first occurrence -->
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="substring-after($input,$substr)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If it still contains the search string the recursively process -->
        <xsl:when test="$substr and contains($temp,$substr)">
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$temp"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="substr" select="$substr"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$temp"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="start-get-id">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count(preceding::INVOICES_ROW) = 0">
            <!--<xsl:variable name="id">
                <xsl:call-template name="INV_ID"/>
            </xsl:variable>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="position() * 2 "/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="position() * 2 + 2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <root>
        <stuff-to-do>
            <xsl:value-of select="STUFF"/>
        </stuff-to-do>
        <file_item_nbr>
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </file_item_nbr>
        <client>
            <client_name>
                <xsl:value-of select="CLIENTNAME"/>
            </client_name>
            <file_item_nbr>
                <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
            </file_item_nbr>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/INVOICES/INVOICES_ROW">
                <invoice>
                    <inv_id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INV_ID"/>
                    </inv_id>
                    <inv_date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST1"/>
                    </inv_date>
                    <inv_text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST2"/>
                    </inv_text>
                    <inv_due_date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST3"/>
                    </inv_due_date>
                    <file_item_nbr>
                        <xsl:variable name="value">
                            <xsl:call-template name="start-get-id"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="result">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$value + 1"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                    </file_item_nbr>
                    <mat>
                        <m_name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="MAT_NAME"/>
                        </m_name>
                        <file_item_nbr>
                            <xsl:variable name="value">
                                <xsl:call-template name="start-get-id"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="result">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$value + 2"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                        </file_item_nbr>
                        <tksum>
                            <tk_id>
                                <xsl:value-of select="TK_ID"/>
                            </tk_id>
                            <file_item_nbr>
                                <xsl:variable name="value">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="start-get-id"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="result">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$value + 3"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                            </file_item_nbr>
                        </tksum>
                        <expense>
                            <exp_id>
                                <xsl:value-of select="EXP_ID"/>
                            </exp_id>
                            <file_item_nbr>
                                <xsl:variable name="value">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="start-get-id"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="result">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$value + 4"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
                            </file_item_nbr>
                        </expense>
                    </mat>
                </invoice>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </client>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

GENERATED OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<stuff-to-do/>
<file_item_nbr>1</file_item_nbr>
<client>
    <client_name>TEST CLIENT</client_name>
    <file_item_nbr>2</file_item_nbr>
    <invoice>
        <inv_id>67447-1</inv_id>
        <inv_date/>
        <inv_text/>
        <inv_due_date/>
        <file_item_nbr>3</file_item_nbr>
        <mat>
            <m_name>BLAH BLAH BLAH 1</m_name>
            <file_item_nbr>4</file_item_nbr>
            <tksum>
                <tk_id>1</tk_id>
                <file_item_nbr>5</file_item_nbr>
            </tksum>
            <expense>
                <exp_id>3</exp_id>
                <file_item_nbr>6</file_item_nbr>
            </expense>
        </mat>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <inv_id>12341-2</inv_id>
        <inv_date/>
        <inv_text/>
        <inv_due_date/>
        <file_item_nbr>7</file_item_nbr>
        <mat>
            <m_name>BLAH BLAH BLAH 2</m_name>
            <file_item_nbr>8</file_item_nbr>
            <tksum>
                <tk_id>2</tk_id>
                <file_item_nbr>9</file_item_nbr>
            </tksum>
            <expense>
                <exp_id>3</exp_id>
                <file_item_nbr>10</file_item_nbr>
            </expense>
        </mat>
    </invoice>
    <invoice>
        <inv_id>142445-3</inv_id>
        <inv_date/>
        <inv_text/>
        <inv_due_date/>
        <file_item_nbr>9</file_item_nbr>
        <mat>
            <m_name>BLAH BLAH BLAH 3</m_name>
            <file_item_nbr>10</file_item_nbr>
            <tksum>
                <tk_id>3</tk_id>
                <file_item_nbr>11</file_item_nbr>
            </tksum>
            <expense>
                <exp_id>3</exp_id>
                <file_item_nbr>12</file_item_nbr>
            </expense>
        </mat>
    </invoice>
</client>
</root>
```

The generated output is what I need to achieve in my real case scenario, however after each invoice the number is behind by 1.

Comment: Why don't you just number the invoices, using either position() or xsl:number, and add 1 to that?

Comment: was just going to say what @michael.hor257k said... also, there are multiple issues here, one being that you will not generate valid XML because you do not have a root element for your output. The other that you start your nested template calls inside the global variable value where you don't have a context node, so start-get-id never gets to otherwise because the count is always 0 so it goes to INV_ID where boolean(.) will always be true and call substring-after-last with an empty string as input.

Comment: so...as a solution, I'd remove all templates except the one matching ROOT and in file_item_nbr use `<xsl:value-of select="position()+1"/>`

Comment: The examples seem a bit contrived. Will there always be exactly one nested item per invoice?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I created these examples as a very basic format, compared to my actual XML. The structure is similiar for the most part, except there will be 3 total nests within the nested group shown above. Each nested group has FILE_ITEM_NBR.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The issue here is: will you be adding an arbitrary (but **constant**) number of items to each invoice, or are you depending on something in the input? In the latter case, you should concentrate on counting the relevant items **in the input document** - not on numbering the output elements as they come out.

Comment: My XML is very basic, and I have to transform it to validate it against the schema for a different companies standards. The invoices are variable, but for each element in the output it is constant. The schema calls for a unique integer for each nested element. The unique integer has to start from 1 and go up until there is no more data. FILE_ITEM_NBR is what holds the unique value.

Comment: If, as you seem to say, the number of items per invoice is constant, then this is a question in 4th grade arithmetic (and I believe Tobias Klevenz has answered it correctly).

Comment: In order for one to do that math, one has to understand XML/XSL and the way position() works.

Comment: That's ok, I am just trying to say that this can be (much) simpler than you thought. If it were me, I would define a $n variable for each invoice = `4 * (position() - 1) + 1` where 4 is the number of items per invoice. Then number each item within an invoice as $n, $n + 1, $n + 2 and $n + 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correct you want file_item_nbr continously numbered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <root>
        <stuff-to-do>
            <xsl:value-of select="STUFF"/>
        </stuff-to-do>
        <file_item_nbr>
            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
        </file_item_nbr>
        <client>
            <client_name>TEST CLIENT</client_name>
            <file_item_nbr>2</file_item_nbr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="INVOICES/INVOICES_ROW"/>
        </client>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INVOICES/INVOICES_ROW">
    <invoice>
        <inv_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="INV_ID"/>
        </inv_id>
        <inv_date>
            <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST1"/>
        </inv_date>
        <inv_text>
            <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST2"/>
        </inv_text>
        <inv_due_date>
            <xsl:value-of select="INV_TEST3"/>
        </inv_due_date>
        <file_item_nbr>
            <xsl:value-of select="position() * 4 - 1"/>
        </file_item_nbr>
        <mat>
            <m_name>
                <xsl:value-of select="MAT_NAME"/>
            </m_name>
            <file_item_nbr>
                <xsl:value-of select="position() * 4"/>
            </file_item_nbr>
            <tksum>
                <tk_id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="TK_ID"/>
                </tk_id>
                <file_item_nbr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position() * 4 + 1"/>
                </file_item_nbr>
            </tksum>
            <expense>
                <exp_id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="EXP_ID"/>
                </exp_id>
                <file_item_nbr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position() * 4 + 2"/>
                </file_item_nbr>
            </expense>
        </mat>
    </invoice>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives the desired result...